# Error while trying to run a discord bot (python)

Tags: python

```
File "dban.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\mabou\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\mabou\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Users\mabou\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Users\mabou\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
create_task = asyncio.async
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: What version of python and discord.py are you running? This looks like a `discord.py v1.0` but for some reason it looks like you got a `python 3.7` verion and you're running something lower. This is erroring out due to the fact that `asyc` was added as a [reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#changes-in-python-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Found [this comment](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1396#issuecomment-414486638) to [this issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1396) on github.

> async and await are only reserved in 3.7 onwards. Renaming library
>   files or folders is not a good idea as it both creates inconsistency
>   in your install and may confuse pip or setuptools if you decide to
>   upgrade those libraries.
>
> It also doesn't help for this issue, where asyncio.async is used.
>   Modifying asyncio in this way will damage your install and prevent
>   discord.py, or really any async library, from operating correctly.
>
> Use an older version or use the rewrite branch to fix these issues.

I don't know what python version you're using for sure but I can assume you're using `Python 3.7` and `Dicsord.py master/async branch`. Either use `Python 3.6` or below, or download the [re-write](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/rewrite).

If I remember correctly the `pip install` is:

```
python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]
```

You can also get quicker more relevant help on the [discord.py server](https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ)