# How do i fix python giving me this error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to code a discord bot and I get this error, I have discord.py installed so I don't know what the issue is im using python 3.8 with windows 10

The code that gives this error:

`import discord`

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I believe, it also says
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
at the bottom

Comment: You can try this prior post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432758/2612429

Comment: S2L that seemed to fix it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code with `python3` in front of it, the async syntax was not supported in older version of Python.

Comment: Asyncio isn't available for 2 afaik, so they must be using 3 already.

Comment: The syntax could be in Python3 but the interpreter could be Python 2, sometimes if you do not explicitly write `python3 yourfile.py` it defaults to Python 2